# History navigation or scripts loading problems with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm kinda new with jQuery Mobile (and web development) and have history issues.

First, the context :

- I must use jQuery Mobile
- I'm using a single page template.
- I've got about 10 web pages for now
- In every pages, I've got a script which loads the menus (menuHeader.html + menuHeader.js).
- menus are loaded on "pagecreate" event

Thing is, I'm "playing" on a page (filling some fields, using the JQM search field on a list, etc.).

When I use $.mobile.changePage to go to another page, I can go back to the first page : I've got the exact state of the page, exactly as I left it.
But, as read on JQM documentation, $.mobile.changePage only loads the first data-role=page of the other page.

=>Thus, I don't have any menus on my next page.

Another way could be to set location.href with my new URL and load my scripts in every pages (that was my first idea).
If I do that, the menus are loaded on every pages but I can't go back on a previous page without reloading it totally.

=> That implies that my forms and my lists are empty, etc.

=> Plus, if I call web services on pagecreate or document.ready, web services seem to be called once again. That's not a big deal for now but could cause performance issues in future.

Is there a method to load scripts on every pages AND being able to use history navigation properly (without having the whole previous page reloaded) ?
A kind of "super" changePage ?

My last solution is to copy my menus in every pages but I'd really like to avoid this as I don't want to have to modify every pages if a color, a label or whatever must be changed.

I'd be grateful for some help (this problem is driving me crazy for a week now)...

Thanks in advance !

Stephane

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile has a persistent header/footer functionality that can serve as a navigation bar.
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html.

All you have to do is add the same `data-id` attribute value to the header footer on all the pages.